# Exclude the number zero from modolus in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, modulus

I'm trying to do a version of the game roulette but I'm stuck at the moment. I have put the numbers 0-36 in a list and from there a pick a random number. Then i put the number in a series of if statements, if the result from modulus operator is == 0 its a black and if its >=1 it's red. But when i come to the green 0 i ran into a problem as it shows both green and black as of the first if statement from the modulus result. So my thought is if i could exclude the number 0 from the first if statement? Or anyone have a better more practical solution for this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

List<int> number = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++)
{
    number.Add(i);
}

int r = rnd.Next(number.Count);

if (r %2 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You got black " + "(" + r + ")" + "!");
}

if (r %2 >=1 )
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("You got a red " + "(" + r + ")" + "!");
    Console.ResetColor();
}
else if (r == 0)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("You got a green " + "(" + r + ")" + "!");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
if ( r == 0){...}
```

to the top if your else ifs

When that is evaluated first, the remaining else blocks won't be.

Comment: Basically if r==0 then there is no need pursuing the modulo. So I believe Sethionic's solution should work. if(r==0){Green}else{Check Modulo}

Comment: That didn't work, I got the same result as before. Two lines with one green and one normal coloured text saying "You got a green (0)! I've tried some mixing around with the statements but without result.

Comment: You've specifically tried
if (r==0){...}
else if (r%2==0){...}
else if (r%2==1){...}
?

Comment: I got it working. Had to make the first one if and the two later else if. Thank you guys for your help!